# What could cause this flyback output current oscillation?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, flyback, waveform

I designed a dc-dc flyback converter that is expected to reach 30 W output power. But it seems there are problems with reaching maximum power. Firstly I tested without the input filter and with non-isolated feedback. Applied 25 V input voltage and 8.6 Ω load. I used a current probe to measure input and output currents. The current probes are set to 1 V/A.

[**Schematic**](https://ibb.co/gSnkrWy)
[image: schematic]

[**Layout**](https://ibb.co/D1J5mZZ)
[image: PCB layout]
[image: Assembly Plot]

**Converter Specs**

Input Voltage: 9-36 V

Output Voltage: 15 V

Output Power: 30 W

Switching Frequency: 200 kHz

Controller: LT3758A

MOSFET: ON Semi FDMS86181

Diode: SS8PH10HM3_A/H

Transformer Lp = 2.4 uH

Transformer Ls = 2.4 uH

Transformer Core: EF20H55

**Test Results:**

(Output Caps. 2 x 10 uF parallel with 1 x 220 uF)

Input Voltage: 25 V (Given in the figure.)

Avg. Input Current: 1.4 A

Output Voltage: 15 V (Oscillating ~1 Vp-p)

Output Current: 1.6 A (Given in the figure.)

Primary MOSFET getting warmer.

**Input Current: Avg. 1.4 A (In: 25 V)**
[image: Input Current: Avg. 1.4 A (In: 25 V)]

**Output Current: (Out. Voltage: 15 V Load: 8.6 Ω)**
[image: Output Current: (Out. Voltage: 15 V Load: 8.6 Ω)]

I attached the schematic and layout. I am not an expert, but output current oscillations are kind of problematic. And MOSFET getting hot while reducing input power (I guess related to RCD snub). How can I fix these oscillations and heat problems?

Comment: I see 3 volts p-p and nothing that tells me that it's current. You haven't said/shown so many things that it's worrying.

Comment: Please show you probe setup.

Comment: What's the total value of the output capacitance? At glance, it seems there's no adequate ripple filtering at the output. Post your schematics because there are many flyback topologies.

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks for your interest. Yes, the current probes are set to 1 V/A. The physical photos are not available right now.

Comment: @Enrico Migliore Total output capacitance is 240uF. 2 x 10 uF parallel with 1 x 220 uF.

Comment: With 35 W in and 24 W out, something is fundamentally wrong. I find it difficult to read the currents from "the figure"s. What is the measured output voltage?

Answer (score 1):

An R+C snubber across the MOSFET, diode or both (Q1, D3) will dampen the ringing.  Whether this is manifest at the input or output (or both) due to common mode coupling or strays of the components, isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try doubling the output capacitance. If the ripple lowers than the problem is that your capacitors have a high ESR and aren't good at filtering a 200 KHz PWM. Try TH aluminum electrolytic caps. SMD is no good.